# Connection in JPA

Tags: datasource, jpa-2.0, jboss5.x, hsqldb, jta

Can anyone tell me how do I get transaction in JPA if I have defined jta-data-source?

Regards,

Satya

Answer (score 3):

With a JTA data source, work done on its connections is part of a JTA transaction. This means you have to start and commit or rollback a JTA transaction.

The easiest way to do this is by doing the JPA work inside a session bean:

```
@Stateless
public class SomeBean {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void doStuff() {
        // … do some stuff
        entityManager.persist(someObj);
    }
}
```

In this case the transaction will start when entering the `doStuff()` method and ends when leaving it.

But if you, for some reason, want to start the transaction manually in some other type of bean (e.g. a JSF managed bean, a Servlet, Servlet filter, etc), you can use the API directly:

```
public class SomeBean {

    @Resource
    private UserTransaction tx;

    public void doStuff() {
        try {
            tx.begin();
            // … do some stuff
            entityManager.persist(someObj);
            tx.commit();
        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            tx.rollback();
            throw t;
        }
    }
}
```

Using the session bean and its so called declarative transactions is nearly always the recommended approach.